# ping a server in lua

Tags: lua, ping

Just curious to see if there is a lua way to ping a server without using os.execute. The purpose being to see if a server is up.

I checked the lua sockets library but I don't think ICMP is supported? Any idea?

Comment: Will you be running this as root? The ping command is suid root on linux, I believe because ICMP requires privileges to use directly.

Comment: No. Preferably not as root. Can't ICMP raw packets be sent using lua-sockets as a normal user? And which packet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no, you can't send ICMP raw packets without root access. That's not a Lua limitation, it's an OS restriction.

To get root access, the best way is to have a small well tested program that's SUID root rather than changing your entire application with Lua to be SUID root. This means you'll end up using os.execute(). And rather than writing your own program, the OS provided `ping` seems to be a nice command for solving your issue.

I agree it's not ideal (especially since this creates OS specific code to handle the various ping commands). But without a SUID function call, I don't think there's any better way.

Comment: There are user mode ICMP sockets since linux kernel 3.0 (i think)

Comment: Any links or details on that @daurnimator? Though if it's only in linux kernel 3.0 or greater, that may be too OS specific for some of the Lua libraries. But this gives the option to roll your own.

Answer (score 4):

You can use io.popen() to execute ping commands.
e.g.,

```
local handler = io.popen("ping -c 3 -i 0.5 10.10.10.10")
local response = handler:read("*a")
print(response)
```

Comment: Not a lua guy, but I think this should work. The answer could be stronger though with an example using popen and reading the returned stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Lua in [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/) on MacOS then it has built in support for doing ping in its [hs.network.ping](http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs//hs.network.ping.html) library e.g: from the Hammerspoon console:

```
hs.network.ping.ping('1.1.1.1')
hs.network.ping: 1.1.1.1 (0x600001d29000)
2023-04-03 12:39:42: PING: 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1):
2023-04-03 12:39:43: 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=0 time=23.463 ms
2023-04-03 12:39:44: 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 time=16.267 ms
2023-04-03 12:39:45: 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 time=16.820 ms
2023-04-03 12:39:46: 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 time=12.700 ms
2023-04-03 12:39:47: 64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 time=13.559 ms
2023-04-03 12:39:47: --- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0 packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 12.700/16.562/23.463 ms
```

There's also an old port of [hping to lua](https://github.com/lxxxxl/hping-lua) which would allow for [hping](https://github.com/antirez/hping/)'s wide array of 'ping' options using ICMP, TCP, UDP, or RAW ....